# Include, require & require_once

Tags: php, object, include, require, require-once

Today I've tried to include file that returns object. I always use require_once, however now I've noticed weird behavior of it.

File main.php

```
$lang = false;
$lang->name = "eng";
$lang->author = "Misiur";
$lang->text = "Text is test";
$lang->undefined = "Undefined";
return $lang;
```

File index.php

```
$lang = include('langs/eng/main.php');
var_dump($lang);
echo "<br />";
$lang = require('langs/eng/main.php');
var_dump($lang);
echo "<br />";
$lang = require_once('langs/eng/main.php');
var_dump($lang);
```

Result

```
object(stdClass)#9 (4) { ["name"]=>  string(3) "eng" ["author"]=>  string(6) "Misiur" ["text"]=>  string(12) "Text is test" ["undefined"]=>  string(9) "Undefined" }
object(stdClass)#10 (4) { ["name"]=> string(3) "eng" ["author"]=> string(6) "Misiur" ["text"]=> string(12) "Text is test" ["undefined"]=> string(9) "Undefined" }
bool(true)
```

Why is it like that? I thought that require and require_once are same thing, only require_once is more safe because it won't duplicate include.

Thanks.

Edit:

But when i use **only** require_once, I get bool(true) too. So require_once returns only result of include, not it's content?

Edit2:

LOL. I haven't noticed, that earlier I had required this file inside of my class which is created before this code execution ($this->file = require_once("langs/$name/main.php");)

So require_once worked as it should. Thanks guys!

Comment: why do you use `return` at all? get rid of it

Comment: without it I don't have $lang object content, only require result

Comment: OMG don't be silly. just get rid of return! Do not use it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you use include and require you get the result of the page you're referencing being included.  When you use require_once it checks and sees that the page has already been loaded using require, so it returns true to tell you that it has been loaded successfully at some point.

Answer (score 7):

That's exactly it, and you're trying to duplicate include.  When you `require_once` something that hasn't been included or required before, you will get the return value.

EDIT: With this simple test on PHP 5.3.2, I get the return value when using `require_once` for the first time.

parent.php:

```
<?php
$first = require_once("child.php");
var_dump($first);
$second = require_once("child.php");
var_dump($second);
?>
```

child.php:

```
<?php
return "foo";
?>
```

It prints:

```
string(3) "foo"
bool(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you do have open and closing tags on both files?  The PHP documentation on [include](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) mentions some of this.  Check out example #5 on that page.

It looks like `include`, `require`, and `require_once` all have the same functionality, just that require emits an error instead of warning, and require_once doesn't duplicate-include a file.

Answer (score -1):

Never use `return` with includes.
Do not return anting and do not assign any variable.

Comment: So how I should do it? Create inside of it class, then after include create object? Or how?

Comment: @Misiur you can do it whatever you want. **You son't need any special code to handle require** Just write it in a single file, then cut the code you want to be separated and paste it into another file, perpending with <?php. **That's all**

Comment: It might helpful to explain why you think this is a bad idea.